# dev_queue_xmit randomly returns NET_XMIT_CN with tun/tap device

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netfilter, tun

I have a userspace program which construct its own packet (App, UDP, IP) and `write()`s it to the TUN device. The packet is intercepted by my own Netfilter module, which it checks if the packet it received is one which we want to process. Then my Netfilter module will `skb_clone()` the original `skb` and create a response packet which I fill in with some data to be returned to the user-space program. To send the response, I use `dev_queue_xmit()`. It randomly returns `NET_XMIT_CN` even though I just created a fresh TUN device and there is no other traffic passing through. If I keep executing the user-space program (sending new packets to the TUN device), eventually the TUN device will respond, but not consistently. I can't seem to track down why it is behaving so erratically.

Essentially I am using the TUN device as a mechanism to communicate from user-space to kernel-space, and vice versa.

Here's my user-space app:

```c
tun_fd = tun_alloc(dev_name);
packet = ... /* Construct request...*/
nwrite = write(tun_fd, packet, packet_len);
...
unsigned recv_buf[1500];
int received = 0;
while (!received) {
    nread = read(tun_fd, recv_buf, 1500);
    ...
}
...
close(tun_fd);
```

Here's my Netfilter module:

```c
static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;

static int __init my_hook(void)
{
    nfho.hook = hook_func;
    nfho.hooknum = 0;
    nfho.hook = PF_INET;
    nfho.hook = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
    nf_register_hook(&nfho);
}

unsigned int hook_func(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    struct sk_buff *clone_skb = skb_clone(skb, GFP_KERNEL):
    ...
    /*
     * Check if packet is for us.
     * Check IP & UDP header, etc
     * If so, parse request, put together response clone_skb
     */
    ...

    if ((err = dev_queue_xmit(clone_skb)) != 0) {
        printk(....)
        /* Either it return 0 (success) or 2, meaning NET_XMIT_CN */
    }

    return NF_STOLEN;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out this behavior. Am I misusing the TUN device? Is there an easier way than this?

Please let me know if I should provide any extra details or clarify something.